# Modifying an existing duplex WCF service to use with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wcf, websocket

I've got an existing WCF service that we've been using to communicate with a Silverlight client, and hence have been using it with the NetTCP binding. I'd like to start using this same service with a JavaScript client, ideally modifying the service as little as possible (i.e., allowing Silverlight and JS clients to call the same duplex service). Ideally this would happen through a reasonably performant and scalable tech, like WebSockets, rather than a hack like Comet.

What's the best way to do this?

Adding WebSocket support to the service (through the [NetHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674273.aspx)) would seem like one obvious way to do it - but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to call the resulting service from JavaScript. I suppose I could configure it to use a text-based transport, instead of the default binary transport, and then hack together some sort of JavaScript-based SOAP client (perhaps using [WSDL2JS](http://wsdl2js.sourceforge.net/)) to call it. That feels like it ought to work, but also pretty awkward, and with some pieces in the mix that haven't been well documented.

I could also re-implement my service in a framework like [XSockets](http://xsockets.net/) or [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/), but that's some real work, and keeping it in sync with the WCF implementation would be more on top of that.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you could try SignalR with WCF as a "web socket" (depending on the version of the FWK you are using). http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/real-time-system-resource-monitor-with-signalr-wcf-and-knockoutjs/

Comment: i think the best way here is to add binding to rest - quick search in g will help here

Comment: @ItayKinnrot - The service is (and needs to be) duplex, i.e., needs to be able to call methods on the client. I'm not aware of any way to do that with a REST service.

Comment: @Gabobcat - By the way, I give up. What does "FWK" mean? Presumably not this . . . http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fwk

Comment: @KenSmith "Framework", I meant the .NET framework version you are using to implement WCF. Anyway, good to know about XSockets.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am one of the guys behind XSockets.NET. I can help you with this one I hope.
XSockets has a "external" API that you can use from WCF (or anything else talking TCP/IP and .NET) to send messages to the XSockets server. The server will then pass the messages (pub/sub pattern) to the client(s) and vice versa.

So, there will be almost no changes to your WCF.

Just tell me if you need an example, and I will provide one for you. Just send me an email on uffe at xsockets dot net and we can take it from there.

EDIT: Created a example on howto boost your WCF to realtime. It´s on GitHub: [Boost WCF to RealTime](https://github.com/codeplanner/XSocketsWCF)

Regards
Uffe, Team XSockets